# Unzip file progress not working inside block

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, progress-bar, unzip

Currently I am using https://github.com/mattconnolly/ZipArchive library to unzip the compressed folder.It is working fine but I want to also show the unzip progress with it.I am getting unzip progress with ZipArchiveProgressUpdateBlock but progress bar is not showing the progress.check the code below :

```
ZipArchive *zip = [[ZipArchive alloc] init];

    self.progressBarDownload.progress = 0;

    self.lblProgress.text = @"Wait unzipping file";

    ZipArchiveProgressUpdateBlock progressBlock = ^ (int percentage, int filesProcessed, int numFiles) {
        NSLog(@"total %d, filesProcessed %d of %d", percentage, filesProcessed, numFiles);
            self.progressBarDownload.progress = filesProcessed / numFiles;
            if(filesProcessed==numFiles)
                self.lblProgress.text = @"Done";
    };

    zip.progressBlock = progressBlock;

    //open file
    [zip UnzipOpenFile:path];

    //unzip file to
    [zip UnzipFileTo:[dirArray objectAtIndex:0] overWrite:YES];
```

**What I have tried so far :**

I also try to put the progress bar ui changes in main thread but it is still not working

```
ZipArchiveProgressUpdateBlock progressBlock = ^ (int percentage, int filesProcessed, int numFiles) {
        NSLog(@"total %d, filesProcessed %d of %d", percentage, filesProcessed, numFiles);
        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            //Your code goes in here
            NSLog(@"Main Thread Code");
            self.progressBarDownload.progress = filesProcessed / (float)numFiles;
            if(filesProcessed==numFiles)
                self.lblProgress.text = @"Done";
        });
    };
```

Comment: Set some breakpoints and see at what point the chain breaks. Also, to state the obvious, makes sure you have connected your IBOutlet to the progress view.

Comment: Here may be the problem is when zip in progress , the zip process is blocking the main thread so thats why UI also block and progress bar is not updating,

Comment: and ya IBOutlet is already connected

Comment: Well then put the code on a thread ?

Comment: thanks friend I resolved it by background thread...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting the unzip code on a background GCD thread.